# Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.App from 2.0.0-preview3-25514-02 to 2.0.0-preview2-006497

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-restore

I have encountered the following issue.

`Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.App from 2.0.0-preview3-25514-02 to 2.0.0-preview2-006497`

while executing `dotnet restore` over a project with following csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>FoodgetWebapp</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>FoodgetWebapp</PackageId>
    <UserSecretsId>FoodgetWebapp-c23d27a4-eb88-4b18-9b77-2a93f3b15119</UserSecretsId>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.0-preview2-006497</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="node_modules\**\*;Client\**\*" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\dist\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>  

  <Target Name="RunWebpack" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish">
    <Exec Command="npm run clean:dist" />
    <Exec Command="npm run build:prod" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="wwwroot\dist\**\*" />
      <Content Include="@(DistFiles)" CopytoPublishDirectory="Always" />
      <Content Include="app.yaml" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
      <ContentWithTargetPath Include="@(DistFiles)" TargetPath="%(Identity)" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.0.0-preview2-006497" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServicesIntegration" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices" Version="1.1.0-beta-000002" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNet.Security.OAuth.GitHub" Version="1.0.0-rc2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn" Version="1.0.0-rc2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Mvc" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="SendGrid.NetCore" Version="1.0.0-rtm-00002" />
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Twilio" Version="5.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Stripe.net" Version="8.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Webpack" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.4.1-dev-00801" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.4.1-dev-10155" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Bogus" Version="15.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0-*">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0-*">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0-preview2-*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <!-- <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0-*" /> -->
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0-*" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

the concrete error message is as below:

```
error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.App from 2.0.0-preview3-25514-02 to 2.0.0-preview2-006497. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.0.0-preview2-006497" />
```

in your csproj. But because you are using wildcards on all other versions

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServicesIntegration" Version="2.0.0-*" />
```

it tries to get preview3 nightly builds. Typically you shouldn't use nightly builds unless you know what you're doing and just use one of the published previews on the main nuget source